# Get Result (Number) from an sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to get a simple result from a SQL query to make some calculation

My code :

```
cn.Open()

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = " SELECT shift1 + shift2 + shift3 as shifts FROM Statistique where nom_produit=  '" & ComboBox3.Text & "' and p_date like '" & Date1.Text & "' "
cmd.Connection = cn

Dim st As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar

MsgBox(st, 0 + 32, "Your Value !")
cn.Close()
```

The value of "shifts" is what I need. Now I get just 0

Just to make you know, the query executed successfully in MS Access 2007

Comment: the value of " st " is always 0 , i want to get the sum of shift1 + shift2 + shist3 = shifts its somthing like 2700

Comment: And are you sure that the WHERE condition results in at least one record to sum?

Comment: does the problem reside in the query? or the vb code?

Comment: Yes i get the right value when i execute the query in access 2007

Comment: Add % because you are using like. By the way use parameterized query because yours is susceptible to sql injection.

Comment: Side note: Close your connection (`cn.Close()`) before `MsgBox()`.

Comment: the problem is in the date code part ,here " and p_date like '" & Date1.Text & "' " when i use %  % between code i start geting results but not the exact ones cause the date is not matter any more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to change your query to make use of a parameterized query. Keep in mind that a date is not a string. Passing a string for the where clause often will result in an incorrect statement

```
cn.Open()
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT shift1 + shift2 + shift3 as shifts " & _ 
                  "FROM Statistique where nom_produit=? AND p_date = ?"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", ComboBox3.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Date1.Value)
cmd.Connection = cn
Dim st As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar
MsgBox(st, 0 + 32, "Your Value !")
cn.Close()
```

Of course this assumes that your field p_date is a DateTime value in MS-Access and that you type a date and TIME value that could be correctly mapped to the field in the database.

**EDIT** If Date1 is a DateTimePicker then just use the Value property.
The key point here is to pass a parameter with type equal to the field to which it will be applied.
In this way you don't need to worry about conversions or how do you quote the value in a string concatenation.

Comment: i use a dateTimePicker to choose the time just like what in the access database , and i insert values correctly , when i compile your code i get " String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. "

Comment: If Date1 is a DateTimePicker then just use the Value property, answer updated. The key point here is to pass a parameter with type equal to the field to which it will be applied.

Comment: the problem now is just in this part of code : 'p_date like '" & Date1.Text & "' , when i use %code here % i start getting results but time no more matters

Comment: Thank you Steve for the help !